# dependence of braiding matrix element on the fusion product of anyons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, spin-statistics, quantum-statistics

In the case of Majorana fermions (MFs), one knows that if one braids MF $a$ with MF $b,$ then braiding matrix element $R^{c}_{ab}$ depends on the state $c$ which is the fusion outcome of $a$ and $b$. And it is because of this dependence that when one uses the hexagon and pentagon identities of anyons to derive the expression for the $R$ matrix, one gets a matrix (for $a$ and $b$ as MFs) instead of singleton element which gives rise to the non-abelian statistics of anyons. What happens to this solution when one goes from 2D to 3D. In abelian statistics case or 3+1 dimensions, we need to have this dependence on the fusion outcome disappear so that one doesn't get a matrix. Why does this dependence on fusion outcome has to disappear when one goes from 2D to 3D.

Comment: $R^{ab}R^{ba}$ is always the identity in 3D.

Comment: Look at what "braiding" is in 2D, and what it is in higher dimensions. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon#Topological_basis) already tells you the essense of it.

Comment: @MengCheng and ACuriousMind :- I see your point. But instead of asking the question from spin statistics point of view to begin with, I am asking that if you have two MFs, braiding matrix element depends on the fusion state of two MFs. But why this dependence goes away in 3D is physically not so clear to me ?

Comment: It does not go away in 3D. In fact you can "braid" or more precisely, exchange two Majorana zero modes in any dimensions and get the same unitary transformation. The resolution is that in 3D, Majorana zero modes have to exist on a defect (something like a monopole), and the "braiding" is not between point-like particles. One has to take into account the defect. See http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4741 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.0583.